# Is there a way to change edit link for Nodes?

Tags: nodes, routes, navigation

Is there a way to change edit link for Nodes?

Currently Edit looks like this: [node/node_id/edit]

I required to look like this: [node/edit/node_id]

Comment: Yes you can change it, But why you want to change that one?

Comment: It is an requirement from Denmark client, who is doing part development

Comment: Very odd requirement...

Answer (score 2):

Try out this code. add it to your module

```
function mymodule_url_outbound_alter(&$path, &$options, $original_path) {
  if (preg_match('|^node/([0-9]*)/edit(/.*)?|', $path, $matches)) {
    if ($node->nid == $matches[1]) {
      $path = 'node/edit/$node->nid' . $matches[2];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome answer. It would be great If you add more information on how your code works actually.

Comment: is it works for you?

Comment: I'm aware of the hook_url_outbound_alter(), but haven't tried  this one. Hope it works for you :)

Comment: url is swapped, but it doesnt redirect to page and drupal throws page not found error.

Comment: what result u got here? url??